# Passing empty value hash key in params within Rspec let

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am passing a hash key value pair in `let`:

```
let(:request_params) {
  { a: { b: %w[firstname lastname] }, c: { } }
}
```

When I check the relevant controller, it receives:

```
params
# => <ActionController::Parameters {
#   "a"=><ActionController::Parameters {"b"=>["firstname", "lastname"]} permitted: false>,
#   "format"=>:json,
#   "controller"=>"abc",
#   "action"=>"create"
# } permitted: false>
```

I want to know where `c` key goes, and how I can access it.

Comment: That rings a bell. See if this helps: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1833

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. I get: `require "action_controller";
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(a: {b: %w[foo bar]}, c: {})
# => <ActionController::Parameters {"a"=>{"b"=>["foo", "bar"]}, "c"=>{}} permitted: false>`

Comment: @sawa have you tried through RSpec let variable.

Comment: Have you tried without it? I don't think that makes any difference.